# Why startActivityForResult() method doesn't work in this case

Tags: java, android

I tried to get data from the second activity so I use startActivity method to achieve this goal.

```
    final EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
    final String text=editText.getText().toString();
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(text);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

What confuse me is when I put the "text" in Uri.parse(),it doesn't work,so I   change to Uri.parse(editText.getText().toString),it just works.

So what exactly is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did this:

```
final String text=editText.getText().toString();
```

the `final` keyword "freezes" the value of text (to probably an empty string since it looks like you are in an init function).  So whenever you use `text` inside `onClick()` it will refer to the frozen value of `text`.  If you want the current value of `editText` at the time that the button is clicked, you need to obtain the value inside `onClick()`:

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse(editText.getText().toString()));
```

Note that you do need the `final` keyword for `editText` or else you would not be able to use it inside `onClick()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because it will has different value :

You put this code **outside** the `onClick` :

```
final String text=editText.getText().toString();
```

So, `Uri.parse(text)` will return the text **before** the `onClick` happened.

But if you use `Uri.parse(editText.getText().toString)`,  it will parse the text when the `onClick` called (realtime).